# Is there a way to create a facebook plugin which can be placed on user's facebook home page

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook app that runs in an iFrame. I want to find a way to host this app on the user's home page instead of visiting my app page. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, I believe that Facebook removed this functionality a year or so ago with a redesign of the platform.